# Why my arduino board does not blink properly?

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, port-mapping, avr-gcc

I have two files

blink1.cpp

```
typedef unsigned char int8_t;
typedef volatile int8_t * volatile port_type;


port_type portB = (port_type) 0x25;
port_type ddrB = (port_type) 0x24;


void delay_500ms()
{
    asm (
    // 8000000 cycles
    "ldi  r19, 150 \n\t"
    "ldi  r20, 128 \n\t"
    "ldi  r23, 41 \n\t"
    "L1: \n\t"
    "dec  r20 \n\t"
    "brne L1 \n\t"
    "dec  r19 \n\t"
    "brne L1 \n\t"
    "dec  r23 \n\t"
    "brne L1 \n\t"
    );
}

int main()
{
    ddrB = (port_type) 0x20;

    while(true)
    {
        *portB = (int8_t) 0x20;
        delay_500ms();
        *portB = (int8_t) 0x00;
        delay_500ms();
    }
}
```

[image: Blink1]

blink2.cpp

```
typedef unsigned char int8_t;
typedef volatile int8_t * volatile port_type;


port_type portB = (port_type) 0x25;
port_type ddrB = (port_type) 0x24;
port_type portC = (port_type) 0x28;
port_type ddrC = (port_type) 0x27;
port_type portD = (port_type) 0x2B;
port_type ddrD = (port_type) 0x2A;


void delay_500ms()
{
    asm (
    // 8000000 cycles
    "ldi  r19, 150 \n\t"
    "ldi  r20, 128 \n\t"
    "ldi  r23, 41 \n\t"
    "L1: \n\t"
    "dec  r20 \n\t"
    "brne L1 \n\t"
    "dec  r19 \n\t"
    "brne L1 \n\t"
    "dec  r23 \n\t"
    "brne L1 \n\t"
    );
}

int main()
{
    ddrB = (port_type) 0x20;

    while(true)
    {
        *portB = (int8_t) 0x20;
        delay_500ms();
        *portB = (int8_t) 0x00;
        delay_500ms();
    }
}
```

[image: Blink2]

---

The difference between these two files are the definition of only a few unused ports in blink2.

I compile and upload them to the board by

```
avr-g++ blink1.cpp -o blink1
avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom blink1 blink1.hex
avrdude -F -V -c arduino -p ATMEGA328P -P /dev/ttyUSB0 -b 115200 -U flash:w:blink1.hex


avr-g++ blink2.cpp -o blink2
avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom blink2 blink2.hex
avrdude -F -V -c arduino -p ATMEGA328P -P /dev/ttyUSB0 -b 115200 -U flash:w:blink2.hex
```

The first one does not blink properly but the second one does. What is the problem of the first code?

Comment: Do both files behave the same when using `avr-g++ -Os blink1/2.cpp -o blink1/2` for compilation?

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt, using `-Os` both act as before.

Comment: I think `ddrB = (port_type) 0x20;` should be `*ddrB = (int8_t) 0x20;` no?

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt, You are correct. However, this fix does not change anything. The board behavior highly depends on the variable you define after ddrB and its value.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt, it is interesting that when I use `*ddrB = (int8_t) 0x20;
` with `-Os`, the LED turns on but does not blink. If I do not use `-Os` it will blink fine.

Comment: Maybe you're killing the contents of registers that are being used. Check the disassembly to see if the registers you are using in assembly are being pushed to the stack before use and popped off afterwards - if they aren't then you should be doing that manually.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Clobbers-and-Scratch-Registers

Comment: You may want to exchange the assembly code for C code for a test and see if that's the problem, e.g. with the code https://pastebin.com/Z5m2fvWt

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt: Your `delay_500ms()` is more than an order of magnitude slower than the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.

One of them has already been raised in a comment:

```
 
 int main()
 {
-    ddrB = (port_type) 0x20;
+    *ddrB = (int8_t) 0x20;
 
     while(true)
     {
```

The more serious issue is in the command line you used to compile the
program. When compiling for an Uno, you should add the option
`-mmcu=atmega328p`. This way the compiler knows which version of the C
runtime it should add to your program. Otherwise the compiler will
include no runtime at all.

The C runtime does some important initializations. For example, it
clears the register `r1`, which is *required* by the ABI, and *assumed*
to be the case by the compiler. For example, when you write `*portB = (int8_t) 0x00;`, the compiler copies `r1` to the port, without first
clearing it. Another important role of the C runtime is to call
`main()`. Without it, the program will start by executing whichever
function happens to be at the start of the flash. Unless you program in
assembly, you have no control over that. If the first function happens
to be `main()`, the program may work as expected. If it is another
function, that function may then return to the bootloader. Any seemingly
innocuous change in the program can then change the behavior.

Then a few minor issues, that should not prevent the program from
working:

- `int8_t` is meant to be a signed type. If you want the unsigned
  version, use `uint8_t` instead. Sure, these are your own type
  definitions, but creating a type that conflicts with a standard type
  can only create confusion. Best option is to drop the definition and
  include `<stdint.h>` instead.
- Whereas `port_type` should certainly be a “pointer to volatile” data,
  there is no point in making the pointer itself volatile. That can only
  hinder valid optimizations.
- `portB` and `ddrB` should be `const`, and that may allow the compiler
  to better optimize them. But why not use `PORTB` and `DDRB` from
  `<avr/io.h>`?

Comment: I confirm using `avr-g++ -mmcu=atmega328p` instead of `avr-g++` has fixed the problem. Thank you so much.